# Is Model serializers faster than Rabl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, rest, rabl

I am building a rails 3.2.14 web app and API. I want the API part to respond even faster than it does.

My question is this:

1. I am currently using Rabl gem. Is it better (performance wise) to use Model serializers?
2. Is there something I can do to speed up requests (perhaps with middleware)?
3. How can I measure the performance of my API? Is there a tool or a service for that?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding 1) and 2)

Personal preference and prior experience favors RABL. It helps segment JSON views from my code logic. You can get a lot of reuse with partials and other logic within RABL template and this is why I favor it over serlializers. You can take full advantage of Rails.cache in either, and again for me, RABL makes this easier to manage in complex caching approaches ( like russian-doll ).

This is a good write up on caching with serlializers ( http://robots.thoughtbot.com/fast-json-apis-in-rails-with-key-based-caches-and).

Take a further look at ( https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Caching-in-RABL ) for caching techniques.  I've greatly increased performance on heavy APIs by simply using caching.

For Item 3).  I use NewRelic specifically for API performance improvements. You can load test an API, and review the performance to a great lelve of detail in their Dashboard.